# Serialization in Java - Serializing my project and being able to update classes

Tags: java, serialization, save, updates

Im new here and I have made a game in java.
When I am serializing my objects to save the current game, I can deserialize them back normally.
But what if I want to make an update for the game (i.e change few classes, add more fields)? When I try to load back the last game after making a change the classes wont fit anymore the the file I serialized to.
I want to load all the last game's details and the new fields to be initialized as a default I decide in the code.

p.s - Its not a multiplayer game/requires any connection, the files are saved in the computer the game is installed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to provide `private long serialVersionUID`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it for more information

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a long look at the [Versioning of Serializable Objects chapter of the Object Serialization Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html). Acquaint yourself thoroughly with what you can and cannot do while maintaining the `serialVersionUID` constant.

If you think you can't live within those constraints, which are pretty generous, you'll have to use another scheme, e.g. [Long Term Persistence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/package-summary.html).

Comment: If I have a serialized class and i want to remove a field from that class and then deserialize it, it gives me an error. Cant I make the stream ignore the missing field and assign the availble fields? With try and catch?